# ForAll gallery items will get the last gallery item values

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have this gallery which contain items that were already created inside SharePoint, and i want to loop through them and update the items, when clicking on the Submit button:-

[image]

[image]

I tried the below  formula inside the submit button, but the issue is that all the items will get the last gallery's item values, so in the above example all items inside SharePoint will have Quantity = 300 and Quantity Each Network = 500, and so on:-

```
Patch('Printing Orders Details',
    ForAll(PrintOrderDetailsGallery.AllItems,
        {  ID: ID,
           Quantity: Value(PrintOrderQuantity.Text),
         'Quantity Each Artwork':PrintOrderQuantityForEachartwork.Text,
         'Network ID':PrintOrderNetworkComboBox.Selected.ID
        }
    )
)
```

and advice?

Answer (score 0):

`ForAll` is NOT a `for each` function, meaning it's not a function to execute each row one by one. `ForAll` returns a single collection.

Source: [ForAll function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-forall)

> The ForAll function evaluates a formula for all the records in a table. The formula can calculate a value and/or perform actions, such as modifying data or working with a connection.

For example, if you want to filter a collection and return a subset, you can use `ForAll` like that:

```
Clear( ProductsToOrder );
ForAll( Products,
    If( 'Quantity Requested' > 'Quantity Available',
        Collect( NewOrder,
            {
                Product: Product,
                'Quantity To Order': 'Quantity Requested' - 'Quantity Available'
            }
        )
    )
)
```

In your case, you can try something like (you have to adapt the name of the record bind to the inputs of the gallery, and the `ID` property is important to update the related item in SharePoint):

```
Clear( NewItems );
ForAll( PrintOrderDetailsGallery.AllItems,
        Collect( NewItems,
            {
                Quantity: Quantity,
                'Quantity Each Artwork': 'Quantity Each Artwork',
                'Network ID': 'PrintOrderNetwork ID',
                'ID': ID
            }
        )
    );
Patch('Printing Orders Details', NewItems);
```

The PATCH method with a collection is documented here: [PATCH Multiple Records In Power Apps 10x Faster](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/patch-multiple-records-in-power-apps-10x-faster/)